# Tag suggestion: analog-hole

Tags: discussion, tags

Its description could come from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_hole):

> The analog hole (also known as the analog loophole) is a fundamental
>   and inevitable vulnerability in copy protection schemes for
>   noninteractive works in digital formats which can be exploited to
>   duplicate copy-protected works that are ultimately reproduced using
>   analog means. Once digital information is converted to a
>   human-perceptible (analog) form, it is a relatively simple matter to
>   digitally recapture that analog reproduction in an unrestricted form,
>   thereby fundamentally circumventing any and all restrictions placed on
>   copyrighted digitally distributed work. Media publishers who use
>   digital rights management (DRM), to restrict how a work can be used,
>   perceive the necessity to make it visible and/or audible as a "hole"
>   in the control that DRM otherwise affords them.

Comment: On what questions?

Comment: @Gilles On any question which is about this side of the security. I don't have the required privilege to create this, and even if I had, maybe it would be better to do this with the agreement of the community. This is why I asked it. If the community doesn't agree, then it is not needed. On other metas the tagging suggestions get mostly a positive treatment, but if it weren't so this time, I am ready to close / delete my question. On my opinion, the analog hole plays an important part in the todays IT security.

Comment: Tags are created by editing a question. Creating a tag with no corresponding question is not just pointless, it's impossible.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, but it requires 1000 reputation what I don't have. I've meet first the formula in [this comment](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100124/is-it-possible-to-prevent-unauthorized-copying-or-recording-of-data-by-photograp#comment172900_100124), maybe here. If you see this helpful, I can collect others questions for the task, too.

Comment: @peterh please update the question with links to applicable questions. I will add such tag as you suggested if there is need for that.

Comment: @MichałŠrajer I've checked them and found that most of them is in the "physical" tag. I don't know, what to do, maybe a synonym would be also enough. Or I could delete this suggestion.

Comment: @peterh You need just 300 rep to create tags here, not 1k.

Answer (score 7):

Please update your post with links to ones that you think need it. We can then review, and if it is useful, we can add that tag.

The caveat here is, "if it is useful."

Creating tags that don't help out and aren't needed actually negatively impacts the site, so let's see if this tag is going to help.